# An ideal with unit.

Tags: ring-theory

So I'm trying to show that $A=R$ if $A$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ and has a unit.

I want to say this:

Let $a \in I$ a unit. And we know that $a^{-1} \in R,$ so $a  a^{-1} = 1 \in I$

And then I'll show that if $1 \in A$ then $A=R.$ (I have this covered already.)

My issue is that I don't know if I can assure that $a^{-1} \in R,$ I think that probably will be true, but I want to be sure about it, can you please help me noticing that?

Comment: By definition units have inverses in the ring.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to be sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Being of unit of $R$ means being invertible *in* $R$, so that $a^{-1}$ is in $R$ indeed. In what else could it be, btw ?

Comment: The unit was supposed to be in $A.$ But Adam already told me it was by definition that units have inverses in the ring so I guess that´s all I wanted to know.

Comment: I did not see its comment at the time I wrote my answer.